# Javascript validation on multiple input controls

Tags: javascript

i have arrays of input controls and want to check on submit that they should not be empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example function:

```
function valid( array ) {
   if( typeof array != 'object' || array.length < 1 ) return false; // some basic error checking
   var errors = [];
   var alen = array.length;
   for( var a = 0; a < alen; a++ ) {
       if( array[ a ].value.length < 1 ) errors.push( array[ a ] );
   }
   if( errors.length >= 1 ) return errors;
   return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
function submitForm() {
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );

   var errors = valid( inputs );
   if( errors ) {
        var elen = errors.length;
        for( var e = 0; e < elen; e++ ) {
           errors[ e ].className = "error";
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
   }
}

var form = document.getElementById( 'myForm' ).onsubmit = submitForm;
```

If you were using a framework, this would be even easier.

Comment: A small typo, when setting the error class, should be `errors[e].className = "error";`, also I would recommend to use a normal `for` or `while` loop instead the `for...in` statement for iterating the arrays...

Comment: @CMS, corrected all the errors, and I changed the `for...in` s to `for` s, but i'm not sure why you prefer that over the `for...in`.

Comment: the `for...in` statement should be used to iterate over object properties, is not recommended for arrays because it goes up in the prototype chain, and if something extended the native `Array.prototype` object (some libraries like MooTools do it), those properties will be also iterated, another point is that the order of iteration is not guaranteed, so the elements may not visited in its numerical order. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/For...in#section_4